# EMOJI is not supported for my android app

Tags: android

EMOJI is not supported for my android app.If i type the Emoji in edittext box it display as ??.How to Add Smiley/Emojis in Edittext? Anyone one help me to resolve this issue

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/ankushsachdeva/emojicon

please refer this github library.

Note : EmojiconTextView: a TextView which can render emojis.

Note : EmojiconEditText: a EditText which can render emojis.